# Highlight ListItem when it is clicked in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to highlight the list item when it is clicked.I have written the below code but it is not working.I want the particular item in the listview to be clicked.

```
MainActivity.java



 ListView lv = getListView();
                    lv.setSelector( R.drawable.list_selector);
                    // on selecting single product
                    // launching Edit Product Screen
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // getting values from selected ListItem
                            String FC_DATE = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fc_date)).getText()
                                    .toString();

                            // Starting new intent
                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    ForecastActivity.class);
                            // sending lat/long to next activity

                            in.putExtra(TAG_FC_DATE, FC_DATE);
                            in.putExtra(TAG_LAT, LAT);
                            in.putExtra(TAG_LONG, LONGITUDE);
                            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                        }
                    });



list_selector.xml

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Selector style for listrow -->
        <item 
         android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_pressed="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
        <item android:state_selected="true"
         android:state_pressed="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
        </selector>
```

Comment: Set background for `ListView`. `android:background="@drawable/list_selector"`

Comment: How can I enable the orange highlight that occurs when touching a listView row???

Comment: After you set above line to your listview in xml file it will highlight with orange color from your selector.xml file and use listSelector for it

Answer (score 2):

**listitem_selector.xml :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
</selector>
```

**Set list item selector to ListView :**

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector" />
```